# Finding a shared HDD attached to the network from my F-13 machine

Tags: nas, fedora-13

Sorry for the slew of n00bie questions, but here is one more.
I recently partitioned my 1.5TB harddrive according to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/227704/fedora-13-not-detecting-usb-hdd-enclosure-with-hdd)

I then bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CMEIV6) to attach the harddrive to my network.

The problem is, how do I navigate to the hard drive to move files over the network to the HDD.

should this be moved to serverfault?

update: the disk isn't even showing up when i call "fdisk -l" (as root). How can I mount it if I can't even find it?

```
[root@Moonface ~]# /sbin/fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00018598

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       19458   155777024   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/dm-0: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-1: 4764 MB, 4764729344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 579 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-2: 101.0 GB, 101032394752 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12283 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 0):

`fdisk` for the most part won't show you any information about any drive that isn't directly connected to the machine. You need to open the manual that came with your NAS device and read it in order to determine how to configure the NAS device and access your drive.

Comment: but i did nothing in order to access it from my Fiance's windows machine. The drive is available on the network, just not visible to my Fedora box.

Comment: and, in fact, the only documentation that came with my NAS device was a min-CD rom that has the program Bonjour for windows.

Comment: @Ramy: How does your fiancé's machine get to it?

Comment: start->network->SIMPLENET->untitled-a1

Comment: untitled-a1 is the (apparently) default name for the shared-drive

Comment: Does it show up in `Places` | `Network` then?

Comment: nope. I get Windows Network -> MYGROUP -> Moonface (my computer name)